# Powershell: How to access and manipulate the "Count" generated from a .CSV

Tags: powershell, csv

Right now, I have the following code:

```
import-csv $import | ? {$_.'Summary' -like '*apple*'} | Group-Object {$_.'Value1'} | Sort-Object -Property Name| Format-Table  Count,Name -AutoSize|Out-File $export 
import-csv $import | ? {$_.'Summary' -like '*orange*'} | Group-Object {$_.'Value1'} | Sort-Object -Property Name| Format-Table  Count,Name -AutoSize|Out-File $export -append
import-csv $import | ? {$_.'Summary' -like '*banana*'} | Group-Object {$_.'Value1'} | Sort-Object -Property Name| Format-Table  Count,Name -AutoSize|Out-File $export -append
```

My output looks something like this:

```
Count Name          
----- ----          
    4 Juice               
    2 Pie                 
    6 Tart        

Count Name       
----- ----        
   36 Juice                
   1 Pie

Count Name      
----- ----     
   46 Tart
```

I want to take the values output as the Count from my table, and add them together in a variable. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Measure-Object on the content of the files and store in a variable

```
$a = (Get-Content $import | Measure-Object -line )
```

**EDIT**

```
$a = 0
import-csv $import | ? {$_.'Summary' -like '*apple*'} | Group-Object {$_.'Value1'} | Sort-Object -Property Name| Foreach {$a += $_.Count} | Format-Table  Count,Name -AutoSize|Out-File $export
```